# how to extract a href tag elemnt from selenium python?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I am new to Selenium really and would appreciate help in the below case. I am trying to make a birthday bot for Facebook. I am running selenium with js disabled which makes the code easier since it is a little tough for me to maneuver through Facebook's latest UI.
Now, I tried to access the textbox of the current birthdays but that I couldn't so I am trying to extract the profile link of all the friends who have a birthday today.
I have tried using the below snippets, but nothing actually worked.
Both would be helpful if either I can send_keys to the textbox or extract the profile link from

Please check the image for details.

```
birthday = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('bj cf cq')
containers=birthday.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='bj cf cq']")
containers=birthday.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="events_dashboard_calendar_container"]/div/article[1]/div')
birthdayslist= birthdaystoday.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='ce cf cg']")

list=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="events_dashboard_calendar_container"]/div/article[1]/div/ul/div[2]')

//*[@id="events_dashboard_calendar_container"]/div/article[1]/div/ul/div[2]
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ce cf cg")

find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_property("href")
```

[page source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbe2v.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code below (indentation fixed):

```
birthdays = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='events_dashboard_calendar_container']//a")
for birthday in birthdays:
    print(birthday.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, tried your code but getting an empty list,

print(birthdays)
>>>[ ]

Comment: @vitaliis: Thanks for pointing out. Corrected the silly mistake.

Comment: @KUNALDAS: Try now

Comment: I've made a small change to your code. You are welcome.

Comment: @Sonali
HI,
thanks for the response!!
tried the updated code, but the problem is still there,  please check
`
for birthday in birthdays:
    print(birthdays.get_attribute("href"))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-dab438c8a1aa> in <module>
      1 for birthday in birthdays:
----> 2     print(birthdays.get_attribute("href"))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
`

Comment: @KUNALDAS i figure out the error. There was a typo. In Print statement Use birthday.get_attribute("href") instead of birthdays.get_attribute("href"). I have updated the code also

Comment: @Sonali, Thanks your code works!
to fetch today's birthday I just modified it a little bit.
birthdays = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="events_dashboard_calendar_container"]/div/article[1]/div//a')